# Python 3.5 connection.py: sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I have a Python 3.5 script that pulls info from another Linux server.  It must first connect through the 443 port to establish a connection. Unfortunately I get the following error message instead:

I can ping the Linux server but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in     _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
   File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
   conn.connect()
  File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 204, in connect
  conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    raise err
   File "/opt/saddlesum/webapp_Py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
 ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem was caused by a duplicate IP address in my /etc/hosts files.  Once I deleted the incorrect entry everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you finally solved this issues. I m having the same trouble.

I Set Up a wagatail app with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 20. And after the the configurations, here is what I get when I send a message from the contact app.

**Internal server error
Sorry, there seems to be an error. Please try again soon.**

I have sentry running and telling me the errors like this:

1- ConnectionRefusedError /{var}
New Issue
Unhandled
[Errno 111] Connection refused

2 - Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '${ip}:${port}'. The domain name

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31238668)